# Excel - How to move multiple data in a column to 1 singular row (preferably seperated by a comma)

Tags: excel

I am wanting to quickly and easily move the data/text I have in a list to 1 singular row

[image: Example]

so the list in green, I want in a singular row as per column C.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you have Office 365, `TEXTJOIN` is your friend:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,A1:A4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONCATENATE function and add commas in quotes in between your desired cells. E.g.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1;",";A2;",";A3;",";A4)
```